# How to divide two entered numbers in C#?

Tags: c#, percentage, division

`This is my second week of my first Computer Science class so I apologize for what is a very basic question:

"Design and implement a program that asks the user to enter the number of programming majors and the total number of students in a class. The program should display that percentage of the class that is majoring in programming.  "

I've spent about four hours on this now and I thought I was getting there using past problems I've solved and changing up the coding but this is what I have and it just gives me zero for an answer no matter what.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

https://dotnetfiddle.net/P6onoF

Is the code I am using

I just get zero for an answer no matter what I enter`

Comment: Please include your code in your question, as [formatted text](/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Right.

You shouldn't be asking these questions here because the whole point of going to school is to actually learn it instead of asking the solution, BUT, been there, done that... so here we go :D

There's a couple of things you're doing wrong.

1. `integers` "don't divide" (they do, but they sort of don't), you won't get decimal values from them so 1 divided by 2 is 0 although mathematically is 0.5.
2. If you're gonna use int you need to cast the final to a double, you're using `int total = programmingMajors/studentsTotal;` so this is an integer. If you have a total of 10 students, with 5 majors. 5/10 = 0.5 with decimals, 0 in integer. Change it to `(double)majors/total` and you'll have the 0.5  you need.
3. You're not really getting the percentage of the students just dividing the value. To get the percentage you need to use rule of three.

If 1000 students are 100% of the students, X majors are Y% of them.

e.g. 1000 students. 50 majors.

```
1000 students = 100 percent.
50 students = X

1000x = 100 * 50
1000x = 5000
x = 5000 / 1000
x = 5
```

In one single line would be `var result = (100 * majors) / total`

When using types such as int, doubles and decimals always check their range. Use [this microsoft ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types). After changing to double and use rule of three.

I ended up not showing how to do it in your code.

```
// just change the last line to this.
Console.WriteLine("The percent is: " + (100 * programmingMajors) / studentsTotal);
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest write the formula out on a piece of paper first so one has an idea of what one is trying to code.

Also, as mentioned integer values do not have a decimal place, so consider using a different data type such as 'double'.

Also, in terms of display, there is an output formatter 'P' which can be used to format numbers as a percentage.